# How to run an bazel binary executable from repository_ctx

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

In Bazel, is there an equivalent way to run a binary executable as described below but using repository_ctx from within a `repository_rule` implementation function?

```
# def _impl
ctx.actions.run(
    ...
    executable = ctx.executable.foo_binary,
)
```

```
# Is doing the ff also possible for a repository_rule?
bar = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        "foo_binary": attr.label(
            default = Label("//actions_run:foo"),
            executable = True,
            cfg = "exec",
            allow_files = True,
        ),
    },
)
```

The documentation for [repository_ctx](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#execute) suggests that there is an `execute()` function but I am unsure how I can run another bazel-built binary with this. Any examples will be helpful.

PS: I'm new to Bazel. Please redirect if this is not what `repository_ctx.execute` is for.

Answer (score 1):

`repository_ctx.execute()` is similar but is not the same... the fundamental difference is when do they happen.

[`repository_ctx`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html) is available to the implementation of the [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/repository_rules.html):

> An external repository is a rule that can be used only in the WORKSPACE file and enables non-hermetic operation at the loading phase of Bazel

Whereas [`ctx`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/ctx.html) is used in rule implementation which gets [evaluated](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/concepts.html#evaluation-model) in *analysis phase*.

In other words. `repository_ctx.execute()` is really meant to run (non-hermetic) tools on existing on your host (can of course be located in the repo), but this is still well before anything gets built from the tree and could be accesses to be executed. If the executable is in the repo tree, you can refer to it by a label (it will get resolved), but it must be already available.